# Passing TestPropertySource location has no affect

Tags: java, spring-boot, testing, junit, spring-boot-test

I am trying to pass a `test.properties` file to the `@TestPropertySource` annotation like so:

```
@SpringBootTest
@TestPropertySource(locations = "classpath:test.properties")
public class ApplicationTests {

    @Test
    public void contextLoads() {
    }

    @Test
    public void main() {
        Application.main(new String[] {});
    }

}
```

I then call the main application, hoping that `test.properties` will be taken. The `Application.main` is a standard Boot application:

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class Application extends SpringBootServletInitializer {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
    }
}
```

Perhaps I have misunderstood the intended purpose of `@TestPropertySource`?

Thanks for any help

Answer (score 0):

The following is written in the [documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/test/context/TestPropertySource.html):

> @TestPropertySource is a class-level annotation that is used to
> configure the locations() of properties files and inlined properties()
> to be added to the Environment's set of PropertySources for an
> ApplicationContext for integration tests.

So basically, test property sources can be used to selectively override properties
defined in system and application property source.

If `@TestPropertySource` is declared as an empty annotation (i.e., without explicit values for locations() or properties()), an attempt will be made to detect a default properties file relative to the class that declared the annotation. For example, if the annotated test class is `com.example.MyTest`, the corresponding default properties file is "`classpath:com/example/MyTest.properties`". **If the default cannot be detected**, an `IllegalStateException` will be thrown.

In your case, file `test.properties` should be placed in `resources` folder.

You can check this [example](https://www.javarticles.com/2016/02/spring-testpropertysource-annotation-example.html) to see how it works in action.

Comment: Thanks @Nemanja - this approach does not work and also test.properties should go in the test/resources folder. Thanks.

Comment: @user1472672 what exacly doesn't work?

Comment: It gives the same error as described. Thanks.